# How do I load VMDK backups into a VMWare server?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

It's a long story, but one of my VMs ended up not being backed up through Veeam, but we DO have the raw nvram, vm*, and log files.  It appears that I need to load it onto our ESXi server's datastore.  However, I've not been able to find a way with vSphere.  The thick client is available, but I don't see an option for loading onto the datastore.  The thin client website version won't load, throwing errors about Adobe Flash failing to load.  Is there a way to do something like SFTP?  Some other method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have SSH enabled, you can scp/sftp the files into a directory on the datastore. Or you can use the thick client "Browse Datastore" to upload files.

Once the files are there, right-click on the `vmx` file and "Add to Inventory".

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that there was a Datastores options under Inventory...  Works perfect!